# Cron code with wamp & zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, wamp

I want to use cron in my zend framework. Please just guide me through a simple example how to implement this. I want to use it with the following s/w : Zend Framework with windows 7 with wamp server on my localhost. Please also tell me where to write the code or any other information to run this.

"My main purpose is to send a mail everyday to the client".

Thanks

Comment: There are quite a few tasks involved in this whole process and I don't see a specific problem or question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under windows you need to create a [task](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/12444-task-scheduler-create-new-task.html).

Then you need a `*.bat` file that opens the web address (`http://localhost/PATH_TO_CONTROLLER_ACTION`).

There are a windows version of [wget](http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/) available so you can use it in your bat file.

Look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/402021/http-invoke-url-by-windows-task-scheduler-schtasks-exe) for more info.